# set alias for a directory

Tags: alias, tcsh, hp-ux

I am trying to set an alias that would allow me to quickly `cd` to the following directories:

```
/home/user/asreera/Aravind/sample/src
/home/user/asreera/Aravind/sample2/src
```

First I set the variable:

```
set use=/home/user/asreera/Aravind/
```

Then I've set alias:

```
alias mov 'cd $use/*/src'
```

My intended usage is:

```
mov sample
```

It should go to directory `/home/user/asreera/Aravind/sample/src`.

In case of `mov sample2` it should go to directory `/home/user/asreera/Aravind/sample2/src`

When I use this alias I'm getting an error `cd:too many arguments`

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong in this?

Comment: Wild cards are not magical and there is no way this can be done automatically without much clearer specs.  Once you figure out exactly how it could be done logically, write it in a shell script and make use that instead of an alias.

Comment: `*` does not do what you think it does. You can use a shell function: `$1` would then go where you put the `*`.

Comment: @richard How do you define a function in tcsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
alias mov 'cd "$use"/\!*/src'
```

`!*` in csh/tcsh alias resolves to all arguments of the command being run (i.e. what you put after `mov`).

See [Writing Aliases in `csh` and `tcsh`](http://home.adelphi.edu/sbloch/class/archive/271/fall2005/notes/aliases.html) for other options:

- `!!` is the whole command line
- `!*` is all the arguments of the command
- `!:1` is the first argument of the command
- `!:2` is the second argument of the command
- `!$` is the last argument of the command

Each must be escaped by `\`.

---

> Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong in this?

When you execute:

```
mov sample
```

Shell resolves the alias to:

```
cd $use/*/src sample
```

Then expands the variable and executes:

```
cd /home/user/asreera/Aravind//*/src sample
```

`cd` command complains it has too many arguments.

Comment: @techarf Could you please explain importance of "!" here? what exactly it is doing

Comment: `!*` in csh alias resolves to all arguments of the command being run (i.e. what you put after `mov`). See [this](http://home.adelphi.edu/sbloch/class/archive/271/fall2005/notes/aliases.html) for other options.

Comment: `alias mov 'cd "$use"/\!:1/src'` might make more sense — it doesn't make sense for this alias to be called with more than one argument. P.S. You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$use"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

Comment: No it doesn't make sense, imho, for this very reason. If you call the alias with more than one argument it is better to fail than take its first argument and pretend everything was ok.

Comment: @techraf can I use this same concept in `ksh`